# Impersonate users in a different Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, impersonation

I have a company network which my computer joins domain to. (Company_Domain)
We have setup a test AD (Test_Domain).
I have to impersonate user in ASP.NET using credential in Test_Domain. Is it feasible?

(I have read this article [Using advapi32.dll:LogonUserA() to impersonate a remote machine's local user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035116/using-advapi32-dlllogonusera-to-impersonate-a-remote-machines-local-user) but it only allow me to impersonate users in Company_Domain.)